# Simple Python Print Command Giving Unsupported Type Error

Tags: python

No clue why but this simple Python code is giving me an error:

```
'''
Created on Aug 2, 2017

@author: Justin
'''

x = int(input("Give me a number, now.....")) 
if x % 2 != 0:
    print(x + " is an odd number!")
else:
    print(x + " is an even number!")
```

The error is saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Developer\Eclipse Java Projects\PyDev Tutorial\src\Main\MainPy.py", line 9, in <module>

  print(x + " is an odd number!")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: The error message says it all: you're trying to add together an int and a string. That doesn't work. Convert the int to string and then add them together

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `x` into `str` while printing.

```
print(str(x) + " is an odd number!")
```

Or better you can use `formatting`

```
print('{} is an odd number'.format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an integer to a string. You can however, add a string to a string. Cast x to a string before you add it:

```
print(str(x) + " is an odd number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate  **string + string** not **string + int**

in your code **x** is int type so you can't add directly with string, you have to convert into the string with **str** keyword

```
x = int(input("Give me a number, now.....")) 

if x % 2 != 0:
    print(str(x) + " is an odd number!")
else:
    print(str(x) + " is an even number!")
```

Comment: Did you try running this ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate string into string . but `x` is an integer so before concatenate you need to convert it into string... are use below concatenate method...
try this,

```
print("{} is an odd number!".format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `int` to `str`.

You should  better use new formatting in python:

```
print("{} is an odd number!".format(x))
```